# Difference between a java applet and application

Tags: java, html, browser, applet, web

I've been working on a java web applet (or at least what I thought was a java web applet) in eclipse. After successful tests on my computer, I attempted to embed it in an HTML doc. Next thing I know, I'm swamped with errors. From my research, I now know that these errors mean that I'm using some sort of code that isn't compatible with a web applet. Unfortunately, I have no clue what code is or isn't compatible with the applet, and therefore have no clue how to fix this problem. Quite frankly, I don't even know where to start. The code I have is quite intricate:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;


public class DerpAHerp extends Applet implements KeyListener, MouseListener, Runnable {

int speed = 3;
int andelay = 2;
Thread animator;
Point velocity = new Point(0,0);
Point pos = new Point(50,50);
Point ppos = new Point(0,0);
int imgCount = 1;
Image[] person_S = makeAnimation(6,"person_S-","png");
Image[] person_E = makeAnimation(6,"person_E-","png");
Image[] person_W = makeAnimation(6,"person_W-","png");
Image[] person_N = makeAnimation(6,"person_N-","png");
Image personDefault = person_S[0];
Image person = personDefault;
Image offImage;
Graphics offGraphics;
Boolean moving = false;

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


/**
 * @param args
 */

    public void getConnection(){
        String asdf = "";

        try {

              URL ourURL = new URL("http://dannyflax.antserve.com/d/"); //Coding Forums RSS Feed
              HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)ourURL.openConnection();            
              huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
              huc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; JVM)");                        
              huc.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
              huc.connect();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));

              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  // Either do your parsing here, or append it to a StringBuffer for later use

              asdf = asdf.concat(line);

              }
        }
              catch(IOException ioe)
              {
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                 System.err.println("General Exception " + e);
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }


        }
    public void paintFrame(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, person.getWidth(null),person.getHeight(null));

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


        if(velocity.x!=0 || velocity.y!=0){

            if(velocity.x>0){
            //East  
                if(imgCount%andelay == 0){
                    person = person_E[(imgCount/andelay)%person_S.length];
                    }
            }
            else if(velocity.x<0){
            //West  
                if(imgCount%andelay == 0){
                    person = person_W[(imgCount/andelay)%person_S.length];
                    }
            }
            else if(velocity.y>0){
            //South 
                if(imgCount%andelay == 0){
                    person = person_S[(imgCount/andelay)%person_S.length];
                    }
            }
            else if(velocity.y<0){
            //North 
                if(imgCount%andelay == 0){
                    person = person_N[(imgCount/andelay)%person_S.length];
                    }
            }




            imgCount++;
        }
        else{
            person = personDefault;
            imgCount = 0;
        }

        g2.drawImage(person, 0, 0, this);

        g2.finalize();


    }
    public void update(Graphics g) {


        if (offGraphics == null){
            if(person.getWidth(null) > 0 && person.getHeight(null) > 0)
            offImage = createImage(person.getWidth(null),person.getHeight(null));
            else{
                offImage = createImage(1,1);    
            }
            offGraphics = offImage.getGraphics();
            paintFrame(offGraphics);
        }


        Color bg = getBackground();




        paintFrame(offGraphics);


        g.setColor(bg);
        g.fillRect(ppos.x-(person.getWidth(null)/2), ppos.y-(person.getHeight(null)/2), person.getWidth(null),person.getHeight(null));







                g.drawImage(person, pos.x-(person.getWidth(null)/2),     pos.y-(person.getHeight(null)/2), this);

                g.finalize();

    }
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
        update(g);


    }
     public void init() {
         //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.

         addKeyListener( this );
          addMouseListener( this );

     }




@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      int code = arg0.getKeyCode();


      switch(code){
      case 37:
          //West

          velocity.y = 0;
          velocity.x = -1 * speed;
          personDefault = person_W[0];

          break;
      case 38:
          //North

          velocity.x = 0;
          velocity.y = -1 * speed;
          personDefault = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("person_N-0.png");

          break;
      case 39:
          //East
          velocity.y = 0;
          velocity.x = speed;
          moving = true;
          personDefault = person_E[0];

          break;
      case 40:
          //South
          velocity.x = 0;
          velocity.y = speed;
          personDefault = person_S[0];

          break;




      }
}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int code = arg0.getKeyCode();


      switch(code){
      case 37:
          //Left
          velocity.x = 0;


          break;
      case 38:
          //Up
          velocity.y = 0;


          break;
      case 39:
          //Right
          velocity.x = 0;


          break;
      case 40:
          //Down
          velocity.y = 0;


          break;
      }

}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void start() {
    animator = new Thread(this);
    animator.start();
    }


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (Thread.currentThread() == animator) {
        // Display the next frame of animation.
        ppos.x = pos.x;
        ppos.y = pos.y;
        pos.x = pos.x + velocity.x;
        pos.y = pos.y + velocity.y;
        repaint();

        // Delay for a while
        try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        break;
        }
}

}

public Image[] makeAnimation(int size, String name, String extension){
    Image[] imgAr = new Image[size];
    while(size>0){
        String src = name + size + "." + extension;
        imgAr[size-1] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(src);
        size--;
    }
    return imgAr;
}


public void stop() {
    animator = null;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if anything sticks out right away as wrong or incompatible. If anybody could help me with this code specifically or at least let me know how I can start making this code compatible for a web applet, that would be much appreciated. I've already looked at the java applet documentation, but it's quite confusing, especially with how much I've coded so far, as I'm having a lot of trouble weeding out specific things in my code.

To everyone:

this is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<applet
    alt="Aplikacja klienta"
    code=DerpAHerp.class
    archive='DerpAHerp.jar'
    width=500
    height=500></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

errors:

when i load the webpage, I get an error message, and if i click it i get this: http://puu.sh/FZmu

and the console says

CacheEntry[http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/DerpAHerp.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Thu Jul 05 00:50:39 EDT 2012,length=16290

this is a friend of the poster. he went to sleep. =\

Edit (from the poster):
The error log I get is as follows:
http://puu.sh/G6us
Don't know if this helps.

Comment: Could you add the errors you're seeing to your question? Applet deployment can be kind of tricky, so this would help us answer your question.

Comment: Open your html page in a web browser and see if applet is invoked. If it doesn't show up, open web browser's java console and see what the error stack is. Copy and paste the error in your posting.

Comment: also, can you show some code you wrote in html file, to deploy applet?

Comment: `public class DerpAHerp extends Applet`  Take it back to that, add ..a label or something, and see if it works.  Compile and run often.  come back with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), a single copy/pasted error message & a specific question.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
As a matter of fact, I did try that. Because the code I have won't run without the implementations I have, I started a new project from scratch. I made a "hello world" program, then added "a label or something" and it worked just fine. Still, I have no idea how to make a graphic rendering system like the one I have that is compatible with a web applet. Perhaps you know of somewhere I could learn how to do so?

Comment: *"Perhaps you know of somewhere I could learn how to do so?"*  Sure.  I detailed the first step of doing that, in the points after the one you actually did.  Continue with the process..

Comment: So you're saying I should try to make the project again from scratch but this time test it every time I make a big change in order to pinpoint the problem? I think I understand now.

Comment: Please avoid blocks of 5 empty lines - they don't really help in reading code. Another bad idea are generated commments which are lying (automatic generated method body) and `@param args` where no param is given. Comments are meant to communicate about your code, so this is surely something you correct before showing it to others - not later, when nobody will see your code.

Comment: Maybe you can test this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/) and implement to your case.

Answer (score 0):

You applet does not have an **init**-method, so it can't be started. You should read up about applets, because we can't give a tutorial here. [Hiere is the official Oracle page to applets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/applet-137165.html)

Your html-page references a jar, but your code is independent of other classes. You don't need to use a jar.

It can be convenient to produce a smaller output, but for testing a class-file is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:** 
I created a new project by scratch and followed [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-1996/jw-03-animation.html) tutorial word by word to find that the method Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage() is not supported in java applets, but the method getImage() is. I swapped these out, then moved my image loading code to the init() method and found my program working fine in both eclipse and chrome. Thank you for all your suggestions and criticisms. I realize the code I posted is quite immature in certain ways and I will make sure to keep your comments in mind the next time I post a question.